# Having trouble converting a complex javascript object to a query string

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, query-string

Here is the javascript object I'm trying to convert to a query string

```
{$and: [{topic: categoryIds} , {$or :[ {'groups 1': {$ne: ''}}, {groups: $scope.myGroups}]}]};
```

Basically I'm looking to match a topic that equals a categoryIds and grab documents that have an empty groups array or that the groups array has values and matches one in the array $scope.mygroups

My question is what would be best practice to convert this in an easily parseable format so I can append it to a GET request, and how would you go about parsing it on the express server.

Comment: Does this work for you? https://github.com/hapijs/qs/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Can you change that object? It could be much more well formed.

Comment: Why not simply do `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({$and: [{topic: categoryIds} , {...$scope.myGroups}]}]}))` ?

Comment: Have you considered sending this in the as simply JSON?  A something this complex is not something I would put in a query string.

Comment: Since you control the server side code, why not POST it and avoid this issue altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code in production for querying against a server with a MongoDB backend (using angular and lodash):

```js
.factory('mongoQuery', function() {
  return {
    fromJson: function(json) {
      return JSON.parse(json, fromJsonReviver);
    },
    toJson: function(object) {
      return JSON.stringify(object, toJsonReplacer);
    }
  };

  function fromJsonReviver(key, value) {
    var val = value;
    if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
      if (_.isNumber(value.$date)) {
        val = new Date(0);
        val.setUTCMilliseconds(value.$date * 1000);
      } else if (_.isString(value.$regexp)) {
        var match = /^\/(.*)\/([gimy]*)$/.exec(value.$regexp);
        val = new RegExp(match[1], match[2]);
      }
    }
    return val;
  }

  function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
    var val = value;
    if (_.isPlainObject(value)) {
      val = _.extend({}, value);
      for (var k in value) {
        val[k] = toJsonReplacer(k, val[k]);
      }
    } else if (_.isDate(value)) {
      val = {$date: (new Date(value)).valueOf() / 1000};
    } else if (_.isRegExp(value)) {
      val = {$regexp: value.toString()};
    }
    return val;
  }
})
```

It includes many of the suggestions mentioned by others in the comments and supports dates and regular expressions.

Other than that, if you need to send the query with a GET request, just use `encodeURIComponent` like others have mentioned.

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/b9wJiUkrHMrDKWFC1Sdd?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

What you're thinking here is basically to redevelop an API server, coupled with some mongodb database, and querying it with some format.

1. **REST** is the "*best practise*" you're looking for. It's a standard that encapsulates some common actions to http ressources.
2. You should know that you don't need to redevelop an ecosystem based on such a standard. Full-featured REST API servers exist, some are even based on express.js. [Loopback](http://loopback.io) and [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org). These one provide some extra features like

   - Model abstraction through ORM's, and database-engine agnostism
   - Automatic REST actions, from database schema or model finition
   - **Advanced querying through "extended REST" ("where", "limit", "order", ...)**
   - Realtime with REST-like websockets
   - **Client side libraries that help you query the server**
3. Some standalone exernal libraries, such as [js-data](http://www.js-data.io) or [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) can deal with REST server pretty well, and act as a frontend connector to backend

Now, if I had to purely answer your question, and if you realy wanted to go with your solution, I'd just add the mongo query to a `where` query param on the http call with `encodeURIComponent` as stated before.